# Error calling SpringBoot controller using AJAX with a document.getElementByID(#id).val() call?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, response

For my uni project I am developing a SpringBoot web-application and am having issues calling a controller route successfully using AJAX. I have created a dynamic table that selects all objects where X=True using JPA and need to implement a button for each row which will send a request to the controller and remove that row from the database by changing a value to be not true, thus the table when refreshed shouldn't show that row anymore as X=False.

Currently, my JQuery ajax script is causing an error, I am certain I am trying to call it incorrectly do the "data" section but I can't figure out how to call the #athleteID.val() correctly, if that's even what I need to do.  I added the output statements to troubleshoot it but nothing is printed and there is an error:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$("#athleteID").val()"↵ at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)↵
Code:
HTML TABLE

```
<tbody>
<tr th:each="athlete : ${listApplicants}">
 <td id="athleteID" th:text="${athlete.athleteID}">Athlete ID</td>
 <td id="name" th:text="${athlete.name}">Name</td>
 <td th:text="${athlete.gender}">Gender</td>
 <td th:text="${athlete.dob}">Date of Birth</td>
 <td th:text="${athlete.mobileNumber}">Mobile Number</td>
 <td th:text="${athlete.guardianContactNumber}">Guardian Number</td>
 <td th:text="${athlete.applicationStatus}">Application Status</td>
 <td><button class="button" type="submit" id="acceptButton">ACCEPT</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#acceptButton").click(function(e) {
 print('Click works')
 $.ajax({
 type : "GET",
 url : "/applicantToAthlete",
 data : {
 "id" : "athleteID.val()"
 },
 success: function(data){
 //response from controller
 }
        });
    });
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
@RequestMapping("/applicantToAthlete")
@ResponseBody
public String applicantToAthlete(@RequestParam String id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    Long athleteID = Long.parseLong(id);
    System.out.println("////////////////////////" + athleteID);
    Optional<Athlete> optionalAthlete = athleteAuditor.findAthleteById(athleteID);

   Athlete athlete = optionalAthlete.get();
    System.out.println("////////////////////////" + athlete.toString());
    athlete.setApplicationStatus(false);
    System.out.println("////////////////////////" + athlete.getApplicationStatus());
 athleteAuditor.updateAthlete(athlete);
 return "applicants";
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi did you tried below code ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use same `id` for mutliple elements instead use `class` selector also you need to get `td` value using `.text()` .So, change your ***jsp*** code like below :

```
<tbody>
<tr th:each="athlete : ${listApplicants}">
 <td class="athleteID" th:text="${athlete.athleteID}">Athlete ID</td>
 <td class="name" th:text="${athlete.name}">Name</td>
  <!--other datas-->
 <td><button class="button" type="submit" class="acceptButton">ACCEPT</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And your ***ajax*** code like below :

```
$(".acceptButton").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
//get athlete id
  var id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".athleteID").text().trim()
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/applicantToAthlete",
    data: {
      "id": id//pass same
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //response from controller
    }
  });
});
```